# Selenium,Cucumber & Gherkin

Tags: selenium, firefox, gherkin

I'm learning to use the above testing software and was just wondering if there is any way so that selenium detects whatever browser the user is using rather then a specific driver having to be defined i.e. 
private WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver()

Another quick question is how can I loop a test so that it repeats a set number of time?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/). It has all configuration out side the code. For example you don't need to specify which driver you need to initiate in code instead you can provide as property in property file or in run configuration file like:

```
driver.name=firefoxDriver
```

There are lots of features specific to web, mobile web and native automation.
Here you can find [step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Java you could specify the browser in a [properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Failing that, you could use an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Or you could put your choice in a file in your file system and read the value.

Lots of choices.